# How to access AWS's dynamic EC2 inventory using Fabric?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, fabric, ansible-inventory

Fabric has a [hosts](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/env.html#hosts) setting to specify which computers to SSH into.

Amazon Web Services has more of a dynamic inventory that can be queried in python using tools like [boto](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Is there a way to combine these two services? Ideally, I wanted something as simple as [ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script)'s approach with an inventory file and using an external file like [ec2.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/plugins/inventory/ec2.py).

More specifically, is there a prebaked solution for this use case? Ideally, I would like to run something straightforward like this:

```
from fabric.api import env, task
import ec2
env.roledefs = ec2.Inventory()

@task
def command():
    run("lsb_release -a")
```

And run it like so, assuming `env.roledefs['nginx']` exists:

```
$ fab -R nginx command
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use fabric and boto concurrently.
First you need to export the aws_secret_key, aws_secret_access_key and default regions from your console. Fabric file name should be fabfile.py and should not ec2.py/other.

```
import boto, urllib2
from   boto.ec2 import connect_to_region
from   fabric.api import env, run, cd, settings, sudo
from   fabric.api import parallel
import os
import sys
REGION       = os.environ.get("AWS_EC2_REGION")
env.user      = "ec2-user"
env.key_filename = ["/home/user/uswest.pem"]
@task
def command():
    run("lsb_release -a")
def _create_connection(region):
    print "Connecting to ", region
    conn = connect_to_region(
        region_name = region, 
        aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"), 
        aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
    )
    print "Connection with AWS established"
    return connection
```

Finally this program can be executed by using below command.

```
$ fab command
```

Comment: Did you get this from http://abhishek-tiwari.com/hacking/interacting-with-tagged-ec2-instances-using-fabric ? Seems pretty useful, but I'll have to play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/admin/

You can see that if you set
env.hosts = ['my_server1', 'my_server2']

You'll then be able to target those hosts.

With boto, if you just have a function that does
ec2_connection.get_only_instances(filter={'tag':< whatever>})
and returns a list of their dns names, you'll be able to then set 
env.hosts = [< list of dns names from ec2>]

Piece of cake!